# How to find the parent model of a polymorphic nested resource in the index action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, url-routing

I want to determine the parent model of a nested resource in the `index` action.

(**Important:** I'm asking about the `index` action only. In all other REST actions it's trivial to find the parent model. Also it has been answered a couple of times on SO)

I have these routes:

```
resources people do
  resources addresses, only: [:index]
end
resources locations do
  resources addresses, only: [:index]
end
resources events do
  resources addresses, only: [:index]
end
```

In the `index` action of my `AddressesController` I want to load the parent model, but depending on the matched route, the parameter *name* containing the parent ID changes:

```
/people/1/addresses     ->  person_id
/locations/1/addresses  ->  location_id
/events/1/addresses     ->  event_id
```

Right now I have this ugly piece of code in my `index` action:

```
if params[:person_id]
  parent_id = params[:person_id]
  parent_type = Person
elsif params[:location_id]
  parent_id = params[:location_id]
  parent_type = Location
else params[:event_id]
  parent_id = params[:event_id]
  parent_type = Event
end

@addresses = Address.where(
       addressable_type: parent_type, 
       addressable_id: parent_id)
```

What bothers me the most is that I have to update my controller whenever I add a new nested route.

Is there any better way to determine the parent model? (Besides simply refactoring the code above)

Comment: My approach has been very similar to what you have above. I hope someone can give you a good answer because I'd love to clean it up as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1 approach: your case with parent_type/parent_id**

```
before_filter :polymorphic_resource

def polymorphic_resource
  request.path_parameters.each do |key, value|
    if key =~ /_id\z/
      resource_name = key.gsub(/_id\z/, "")
      @parent_type = resource_name.classify.constantize
      @parent_id = value
    end
  end
end

@addresses = Address.where(
       addressable_type: @parent_type, 
       addressable_id: @parent_id)
```

**2 approach: Recommended**

```
before_filter :polymorphic_resource

def polymorphic_resource
  request.path_parameters.each do |key, value|
    if key =~ /_id\z/
      resource_name = key.gsub(/_id\z/, "")
      @resource = resource_name.classify.constantize.find(value)
    end
  end
end

@addresses = @resource.addresses
```

**3 approach: Set instance variables named as default. For specific needs...**

```
before_filter :polymorphic_resource

def polymorphic_resource
  request.path_parameters.each do |key, value|
    if key =~ /_id\z/
      resource_name = key.gsub(/_id\z/, "")
      instance_variable_set("@#{resource_name}", resource_name.classify.constantize.find(value))
    end
  end
end

@addresses = ...
```

Comment: I give a broader answer, because this is a common question. Fetch the parent object can be useful in other actions.